# Project cannot be loaded (Netbeans IDE)

Tags: java, netbeans

I downloaded the archive with the project, and unpacked it. I threw it in the project folder, but when I open it through Netbeans IDE - I get an error (Project cannot be loaded) and missing package with codes
It is strange that on another computer it opens a project without problems
Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:

```
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar is missing. @ line 22, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.projectlombok:lombok:jar is missing. @ line 33, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar is missing. @ line 39, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar is missing. @ line 43, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-core:jar is missing. @ line 54, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar is missing. @ line 58, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-context:jar is missing. @ line 62, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-web:jar is missing. @ line 66, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar is missing. @ line 70, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-orm:jar is missing. @ line 74, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-tx:jar is missing. @ line 78, column 21
```

Comment: Maven dependencies were not downloaded. If issue persists, before importing into Netbeans, execute maven lifecycle command to download all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that the project, you've copied, references another project. If you open pom.xml there probably is a section "parent" there, where a parent project is defined:

```
<!-- Identifier of the parent project -->
<parent>
    <groupId>...group of your parent project...</groupId>
    <artifactId>... artefactId of your parent project ...</artifactId>
    <version>... version of your parent project ...</version>
</parent
```

This parent project probably contains dependencies with versions. Child module, you've copied, contains dependencies without versions:

```
<!-- Version of the dependency is defined in parent pom in dependencyManagement section -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <!-- here should be the version -->
</dependency>
```

You either need to copy the parent project on your computer as well or set all the dependencies versions manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Spring Boot project. To have it displayed correctly in Netbeans:

- Open the project in Netbeans
- [Add Maven Central to your list of repositories](https://medium.com/@chris.shellenbarger/public-maven-repositories-maven-central-and-more-a0dfc0b61c0)
- Right click on the project and run Build.
- During the build the artifact `spring-boot-starter-parent` is downloaded to your local maven repository and now Netbeans can display the project correctly.